# javascript creating object key

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this:

```
var ObjectKey = "06.2012";
```

It's a string that represents the month. I want to use this value as the key of a new object. I have

```
TheObject = {ObjectKey: null};
```

But when I go to the console, instead of the TheObject having a key named 06.2012, it has a key named ObjectKey.

How do I create a key that has the name of a string that I create at runtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use variable as the key you need to use the `[]` syntax..

```
var ObjectKey = "06.2012";
TheObject = {};
TheObject[ObjectKey] = null;
```

Comment: @Kranklin *chuckle*.. 17 to be exact .. (*and James Allardice was second..*) :)

Answer (score -7):

quick and dirty:

```
eval('TheObject = {'+ObjectKey+':null};');
```

but it's really dirty and susceptible to errors(very suceptible...)

Comment: We should note this method could potentially open your website up for attacks. If the ObjectKey is given from the user, e.g. a form variable, then the user could inject JS code to do anything.